# Can't generate controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The error I get in console when attempting to run "rails generate controller" is:

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
>   4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:239:in `default_controller_and_action': 'Pages' is not a supported controller
>   name.

The line I am trying to run is:

> rails generate controller Pages home rules schedule forum register scrims

Can anybody elaborate as to why this is? I haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the full line you are trying to run?

Comment: Edited question. See above.

Comment: It's a newly generated project. There are no routes.

Comment: Does not reproduce on a newly generated project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to re-install the entire rails suite and ruby... Tedious but it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should call your generate methods with the naming conventions of `snake_case`, meaning:

```
rails generate controller pages
```

is good, but

```
rails generate controller Pages
```

is bad. See remark [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use):

> Only the directory notation is supported. Specifying the controller
>   with ruby constant notation (`eg. :controller => 'Admin::UserPermissions'`) can lead to routing problems and results in
>   a warning.

and the code throwing the exception [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L237):

```
if controller.is_a?(String) && controller !~ /\A[a-z_0-9\/]*\z/
  message = "'#{controller}' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems."
  message << " See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use"
  raise ArgumentError, message
end
```

Comment: Examples from the documentation do use CamelCase though, and it works fine: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller

Comment: I've just tried this and nothing changed. Same error.

Comment: You are right, it is route related, I assumed it is related to the controller generation, since that was the command which the failed in the OP

Comment: There are *no* routes in the routes.rb file. It's a new project. I am so puzzled :/

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had the same and I guess you've changed ruby/rails versions in the Gemfile.

Create new project and check there - check if it's fine.

When you do `rails new project` with one version of Rails than you cannot just do that to upgrade as you already have framework directories/files for the old version.